# Constraints on type parameters - new()

Tags: c#, generics

As per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters), the `new()` constraint is used to ensure that the type argument must have a **public parameterless constructor**. However, consider the example given below (taken from the same page).

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee(string name, int id)
    {
        Name = name;
        ID = id;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

class EmployeeList<T> where T : Employee, new()
{

}
```

Here, the `Employee` type does not have a parameterless/default constructor, yet this code compiles successfully. Can someone please elaborate on the usage of this constraint and why this works?

Comment: @Jonesopolis The constructor is defined, it just uses the expression body syntax instead of the usual one. I'll update the syntax to the usual ctor syntax to make the question more straightforward.

Comment: yep, the expression body made me glance right over it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code compiles because it's entirely possible to have a type derived from `Employee` with a parameterless constructor - and that's what the constraint says. The constraint is *not* trying to say that `Employee` itself has a parameterless constructor, and indeed an attempt to use `EmployeeList<Employee>` would fail as the constraint isn't satisfied.

As example of what *would* be valid:

```cs
public class GeneratedEmployee : Employee
{
    public GeneratedEmployee() : base(GenerateName(), GenerateId())
    {
    }

    private static string GenerateName()
    {
        // Implementation here
    }

    private static int GenerateId()
    {
        // Implementation here
    }
}
```

At that point, it's fine to create an `EmployeeList<GeneratedEmployee>`, and assuming the `EmployeeList<>` class uses `new()` somewhere in the implementation, it would call the parameterless constructor of `GeneratedEmployee`.

That said, it's a pretty *odd* constraint, as I wouldn't expect you to *really* want to create an employee without specifying the name and ID.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. I did not consider the possibility of creating a derived class with a parameterless constructor and passing values to the base ctor as you've described.

Answer (score 2):

> Here, the Employee type does not have a parameterless/default constructor, yet this code compiles successfully

That's correct, however what you haven't tried is to actually use the class. What doesn't compile is actually trying to call `EmployeeList<Employee>`:

```
CS0310 'Employee' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'EmployeeList<T>'
```

As you correctly quote, `Employee` doesn't match the constraint `T : Employee, new()`. The only way to give it something that will match it is to derive a class from `Employee` that does implement a default constructor, and provide that.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. I did not consider the possibility of creating a derived class with a parameterless constructor when the base class constructor is parameterized.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
class EmployeeList<T> where T : Employee, new()
{

}
```

`T` must be `Employee` descendant of `Employee` with parameterless constructor but the fact that `Employee` does not have one does not mean that it's descendants can't have it.

i.e. `new()` constraint will prevent `new EmployeeList<Employee>();` from compiling, but you can do:

```
class EmployeeChild : Employee
{
    public EmployeeChild() : base("", 1)
    {
    }
}
```

Which will satisfy all constraints and `new EmployeeList<EmployeeChild>();` will compile just fine.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. I did not consider the possibility of creating a derived class with a parameterless constructor and passing values to the base ctor as you've described.

Answer (score 1):

Your list says that the class must be an Employee, or derived from Employee.  Employee itself does not have a parameterless constructor, so it would fail as the type argument:

```
//fails to compile
var xx = new EmployeeList<Employee>()
```

But, if you defined a class that inherited from Employee:

```
public class EmployeeDerived : Employee
{
    public EmployeeDerived() : base("test", 123)
    {

    }
}
```

This class does have a parameterless constructor (though it's pretty useless). So the compiler can use it as the `T` to EmployeeList

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. I did not consider the possibility of creating a derived class with a parameterless constructor and passing values to the base ctor as you've described.

Answer (score 1):

Even though `Employee` doesn't have a parameterless constructor, a subclass of `Employee` *can*!

```
public class Manager: Employee {
    // these parameters don't make sense - just an example
    public EmployeeSubclass(): base("foo", 1) {
        
    }
}
```

Then I can use `Manager` as the type argument for `EmployeeList` - `EmployeeList<Manager>`. It satisfies both constraints!

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. I did not consider the possibility of creating a derived class with a parameterless constructor and passing values to the base ctor as you've described.